# How to receive website link in Python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup

I want to collect the link : /hmarchhak/102217 from a site (https://www.vanglaini.org/) and print it as https://www.vanglaini.org/hmarchhak/102217. Please help
[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS6vq.jpg)

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('https://www.vanglaini.org/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
for article in soup.find_all('article'):
    headline = article.a.text
    summary=article.p.text
    link = article.a.href
    print(headline)
    print(summary)
    print(link)

print()
```

This is my code.

Comment: not `a.href` but `a['href']` or `a.attrs['href']` or `a.attrs.get('href')` ( `a.attrs.get('href', default_value)`)

Comment: Thanks I updated my code and I got this error
  headline = article.a.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: it seems not all articles have link so you have check if `articles.a` is not `None` before you get text - ie. `if article.a: headline = article.a.text else: headline = ""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am missing something headline and summary appear to be the same text. You can use `:has` with bs4 4.7.1+ to ensure your `article` has a child `href`; and this seems to strip out `article` tag elements that are not part of main body which I suspect is actually your aim

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

base = 'https://www.vanglaini.org'
r = requests.get(base)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

for article in soup.select('article:has([href])'):
    headline = article.h5.text.strip()
    summary = re.sub(r'\n+|\r+',' ',article.p.text.strip())
    link = f"{base}{article.a['href']})"  
    print(headline)
    print(summary)
    print(link)
```